# Ruby's equivalent to C#'s ?? operator

Tags: c#, ruby, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# ?? operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953216/c-operator-in-ruby)

Is there a Ruby operator that does the same thing as C#'s **??** operator?

> The **??** operator returns the left-hand
>   operand if it is not null, or else it
>   returns the right operand.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The name of the operator is the [null-coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator).  The original blog post I linked to that covered the differences in null coalescing between languages has been taken down. A newer comparison between C# and Ruby null coalescing can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110213024332/http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/3047857892/ruby-is-not-c-so-dont-code-that-way).

In short, you can use `||`, as in:

```
a_or_b = (a || b)
```

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: @orourkedd Thanks, I've reworked it a bit with a new link.

Comment: This is actually a "falsy-coalescing operator".

Comment: Link is a 404 again

Comment: Its not the same thing. Does not work for boolean of other falsy values..

Comment: according to this https://chrisarcand.com/null-coalescing-operators-and-rubys-conditional-assignments/ this is not null-coalescing operator. ||= is a conditional assignment operator. Is this article right?

Comment: ||= is different from ||

Comment: @Cristik Thanks, updated the link hopefully for the last time ever

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind coalescing false, you can use the || operator:

```
a = b || c
```

If false can be a valid value, you can do:

```
a = b.nil? ? c : b
```

Where b is checked for nil, and if it is, a is assigned the value of c, and if not, b.

Comment: I tried `a = b or c; puts a`. Surprise, surprise, in my ruby 1.8.6, it prints the value of b. The reason is that `or` has lower precedence than `=`

Comment: `or` is not a boolean operator but a control flow operator in ruby: http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Comment: Unfortunately the 2nd snippet could have side-effects if `b` is a method (i.e. it's called twice).

Comment: Null coalescing does not exist in ruby. You can upvote a proposal for it here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13820. Author is proposing `??` to match expectations set in other languages (C# and TypeScript). `a = b.nil? ? c : b
` is the closest. The accepted answer is misleading and the real answer is "it doesn't have it"

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that Ruby has specific features for the usual null coalescing to `[]` or `0` or `0.0`.

Instead of

```
x = y || [] # or...
x = y || 0
```

...you can (because `NilClass` implements them) just do...

```
x = y.to_a # => [] or ..
x = y.to_i # or .to_f, => 0
```

This makes certain common design patterns like:

```
(x || []).each do |y|
```

...look a bit nicer:

```
x.to_a.each do |y|
```

Comment: You'll also often see that as `[*x].each do |y|`.