# How to default to zero if the value is nil

Tags: ruby

I would like to have the result as 0 if some_float is nil. How do I do that?

```
some_float = 9.238
or 
some_float = nil

some_float.round(2)
```

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/953388/44853

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just call a `.to_f` before round

```
some_float.to_f.round(2)
```

Because when you call `to_f` on nil, it'll return `0.0`

```
9.238.to_f.round(2) # => 9.24
nil.to_f.round(2) # => 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

```
x = some_float ? some_float.round(2) : 0.0
```

Option 2 (Ruby >= 2.3.0):

```
x = some_float&.round(2) || 0.0
```